# How can I simplify in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, simplify

I want to simplify the following operation, but it yields me an error that says: too many input arguments. Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong???

```
>> 
syms a b c d e  f g h i j k l x y xy

A=[1 a b a^2 a*b b^2; 1 c d c*2 c*d d^2; 1 e f e^2 e*f f^2; 1 g h g^2 g*h h^2; 1 i j         i^2 i*j j^2; 1 k l k^2 k*l l^2]

B=[1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0]

A =

[ 1, a, b, a^2, a*b, b^2]
[ 1, c, d, 2*c, c*d, d^2]
[ 1, e, f, e^2, e*f, f^2]
[ 1, g, h, g^2, g*h, h^2]
[ 1, i, j, i^2, i*j, j^2]
[ 1, k, l, k^2, k*l, l^2]


B =

 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0

>> simplify(inv(A)*B, 'steps', 100)enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I've put the code you pasted in my copy of matlab (R2013a) and it finishes without any errors. The result is not simplified very much though.

If your computer is choking on the computation (it is very long), you could try separating the things a bit and see if it helps.

```
vec=inv(A)*B
for n=1:6
    results(n)=simplify(vec(n), 'steps', 100);
end
results
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call belongs to [this MATLAB function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html?searchHighlight=simplify):

But it is in Symbolic Math Toolbox, which means it can only simplify math formulas instead of complex matrix computation.

```
Simplify Favoring Real Numbers

To force simplify favor real values over complex values, set the value of Criterion to preferReal:

syms x
f = (exp(x + exp(-x*i)/2 - exp(x*i)/2)*i)/2 - (exp(- x - exp(-x*i)/2 + exp(x*i)/2)*i)/2;
simplify(f, 'Criterion','preferReal', 'Steps', 100)
ans =
cos(sin(x))*sinh(x)*i + sin(sin(x))*cosh(x)
If x is a real value, then this form of expression explicitly shows the real and imaginary parts.

Although the result returned by simplify with the default setting for Criterion is shorter, here the complex value is a parameter of the sine function:

simplify(f, 'Steps', 100)
ans =
sin(x*i + sin(x))
```

Instead, I think you could try use [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/simplify1.html?searchHighlight=simplify): 
Simplify(f, Steps = numberOfSteps)

But first of all, you need a 'f' which could be used like a recursion or iteration function.

e.g. `Simplify(sin(x)^2 + cos(x)^2, All)`

Hope this helps!